# Powerpoint - XML - Ribbon - Difficulties with some idMso

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint, ribbon

I hope you are well. 
I am currently creating a customUI ribbon in powerpoint and am facing some troubles with the followings 
 with is not appearing in the ribbon:

```
    <button idMso="TextBoxInsert" visible="true"/>
    <button idMso="Font" visible="true"/>
    <button idMso="FontSize" visible="true"/>
    <button idMso="ShapeHeight" visible="true" showLabel="true"/>
    <button idMso="ShapeWidth" visible="true" showLabel="true"/>
```

I have through Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/f2a8e3c0-14cb-4ad3-88cd-a8b5b1b9a8a0

And tried the following which made the whole Ribbon deseappered:

```
    <tooglebutton idMso="TextBoxInsert" visible="true"/>
    <combobox idMso="Font" visible="true"/>
    <comboboxidMso="FontSize" visible="true"/>
    <combobox idMso="ShapeHeight" visible="true" showLabel="true"/>
    <combobox idMso="ShapeWidth" visible="true" showLabel="true"/>
```

After few tries I still not understand the error nor found a way to fix it.

Does anybody has a idea on it?
Kind regards,
Naxos

Comment: Can you show you code? Where do you set this XML?

Comment: I remove the beginning to make it easier !

Comment: Ok i removed ```visible="true"``` in the TextboxInsert, Font and Fontsize ! 
This is working only missing ShapeHeight and ShapeWidth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct tooglebutton to **togglebutton**.
Add a **space** between the second combobox and the word idMso.
ShapeHeight and ShapeWidth are both **controls**, not comboboxes.

When you're new to editing XML, start with an known good arrangement, make one change, then test. Repeat. Otherwise it's very difficult to identify where an error might be.

Comment: Just a last question on that topic, is there any specific action to perform a keytip action on the controls/togglebutton/gallery functions? On my ribbon the keytip remains the factory ones!

Comment: For a simple one-line descriptor, use screenTip = "Insert textbox". For more complex controls, you can also add superTip = "This button will insert a textbox where you can type text".